Nested SCSS is correct, yet not working in browser?
I am totally stumped. I have nested scss selectors like this:
.entry-content > p,
.entry-content > .wp-block-buttons {

    + .wp-block-columns,
    + .wp-block-media-text {
        margin-top:3rem;
   }

}

Which correctly compile as this:
.entry-content > p + .wp-block-columns,
.entry-content > p + .wp-block-media-text,
.entry-content > .wp-block-buttons + .wp-block-columns,
.entry-content > .wp-block-buttons + .wp-block-media-text {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

And yet, these rules are totally ignored by the browser (tested Chrome and Firefox so far). I checked Chrome Devtools > Elements, and they aren't being overwritten by a different rule -- they simply are not there. It's as if they do not exist.
However, when I click the stylesheet source in Devtools, everything is correct -- the rules are definitely there as written. I've cleared the cache on the server and my browiser -- nothing. I ran the css through a validator, error checker -- nothing.
If I un-nest them and write them in the compiled way in the same stylesheet, they work fine. I'm so confused -- how could this be?
UPDATE:
It appears the issue happens because rule is too long? I had shortened my example above for simplicity, but the full rule was this:
.entry-content > ul,
.entry-content > ol,
.entry-content > h2,
.entry-content > h3,
.entry-content > h4,
.entry-content > h5,
.entry-content > p {
 
        + .wp-block-columns,
        + .wp-block-media-text {
            margin-top:3rem;
       }
    
    }

I started taking away one parent selector at a time, and once I reached just 3 selectors, it worked. I can have as many nested selectors as I want. But once I go over 3 parents, it does not load in the browser at all.
Does this suggest a memory issue? I'm still baffled how it matters if the original sass file was too long, because the compiled version is still correct. And all the other styles that follow display just fine.

How are you building the sass sheet and/or including it in the page?

I'm compiling with a VS Code extension. Been doing it this way forever, and I've only just come across this. And I'm pretty sure it was working in this exact stylesheet a few days ago. I would assume it must be an error somewhere, but VS Code shows if there are erorrs and wouldn't compile if so.

It is being loaded in the page as css/theme.css and it started out as scss/theme.scss

You could try something fancy with :has() and/or :is(). Eg : .entry-content > :is(ul, ol. h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p){/*Your nested code*/}. Docs

What’s the compiled output for the non-working version?

My second code example above is what the compiled version looks like.

Could you make a snippet with the compiled code showing the bug?

If the styles are there, look to be compiled correctly, and do not get applied, the only issue can be that your selectors don't match your document.

Can you show us the relevant HTML structure.
